# density on a line from a planar density distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Let's say we have a two-dimensional Gaussian distribution representing a planar density distribution, now we draw a random line across the distribution, what's the density accumulated on this line?

Comment: Define how you randomly pick a line.

Comment: its zero as measure of the line in 2-D is zero.

Comment: @hunch This is of course true. But what if I insist on comparing the weight of two lines? Since they pass through regions with different density, how should I define a weight for the line so that they become comparable?

Comment: For continuous distribution as in your case, always start with distribution definition not density( actually one should start with distribution whenever one face any basic problem) then you take limit if it exists ..you will get the relation .  If I understand your question, you wish to relate two different lines in density function .  You should write probabilities if lines in terms for distribution, then see if they can be compared.